# ASP.NET MVC ambiguous action methods signatures and are different using get/post

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I know I have done this before and it has worked, but today when I created two methods in my controller and am getting..

> The current request for action 'ContactUs' on controller type 'HomeController' is ambiguous between the following action methods:
>
> System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult ContactUs() on type HomeController
>      System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult ContactUs(ContactUs) on type HomeController.

Here is are my two different both with post/get.

```
<HttpGet>
Function ContactUs() As ActionResult
Dim objModel As New ContactUsModel

    Return View(objModel)
End Function

<HttpPost>
Function ContactUs(ByVal Model As ContactUs) As ActionResult
    Dim a As String = ""
    Return View(Model)
End Function
```

What I don't understand is how these could be ambiguous since they have different signatures and are decorated with post/get.

Comment: In what context are you getting this exception?

Comment: I get the error if I just attempt to go to the page at /home/contactus.  Which if I remove the second method(post) the page loads up fine.

Comment: Make sure you are using MVC attributes btw, as attributes with exactly same names exist under `System.Web.Http` namespace. The once you need are in `System.Web.Mvc`

Answer (score 0):

Andrei had the solution.  For some reason it was using the System.web httppost and httpget.  SO I had to decorate each method with..

```
<System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost>
```